# 403 Error trying to do a post request in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I keep getting 403 errors when I try to do a post request in Django. I disabled `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` and i still have this line

`url(r"viewing_room_capture", csrf_exempt(EmailCapture.as_view()), name="email_capture_endpoint",)`

Why am I getting a 403? It doesn't even look like my view executes, the request short-circuits before the view runs.

And yes I do want to disable the csrf protection on my forms. I seem to remember this working a week ago but I've since rebuilt my local environment from scratch (docker-compose app) and it no longer works. I had 5 working API endpoints before this and now none of them work, I haven't touched this app in 1.5 weeks before coming back to it today and finding everything broken. In fact, I have a development deployment using the *same* application code running right now in the cloud and I'm not getting 403 errors on my API endpoints (i checked the commit history already, nothing that could have caused this was added since my last deploy). My middleware is:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "app.site_translation.middleware.TranslationMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.AdditionalSecurityHeadersMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.CookieMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.DomainRedirectMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.CustomRedirectMiddleware",
    "app.base.middleware.LegacyURLsMiddleware",
    # Can be used instead if wagtail#4491 is merged:
    # 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, it had to do with signing into the application. I can't do a post request without csrf if i'm logged in already.